# Change location of .github folder?

Tags: github

is there a way to move this folder with Issue Templates to .git ?

i have more diverse stuff to fill this file list with, this one just takes space for no use . and i don't want to extend editors with file hiding functions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no use for the `.github` directory, one solution is to simply delete it. You can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60507097/is-there-an-overview-of-what-can-go-into-a-github-dot-github-directory) answer to see what it contains. Many of its contents can simply be moved to the project root (or deleted, if you don't need them).

You could theoretically put them in the `.git` folder, but you would not be able to actually `git add` them (you'd basically be making the .git folder track itself), so you're losing all the benefits of using git in the first place.

Comment: "no use" of it being in the project root . couldn't i include/track certain folder within .git ?

Comment: No.  You cannot check files into `.git`.